# DjangoRestFramework ChoiceField fails float value validation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, choicefield, django-model-utils

I have a question regarding validation logic of `serializers.ChoiceField`. As I've seen in the code, here is `to_internal_value()` of `ChoiceField` that is used to validate client inputs:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    if data == '' and self.allow_blank:
        return ''

    try:
        return self.choice_strings_to_values[six.text_type(data)]
    except KeyError:
        self.fail('invalid_choice', input=data)
```

Here is my declaration of Django model:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel, ScopedModelMixin):
    my_field = models.FloatField(choices=MY_FLOAT_CHOICES, default=MY_FLOAT_CHOICES.default_value)
```

And here is my declaration of choices object from `django-model-utils==2.6.1`:

```
from model_utils import Choices

MY_FLOAT_CHOICES = Choices(
    (1.0, 'choice1', 'Choice1'),
    (1.5, 'default_value', 'Choice2'),
    (2.0, 'choice3', 'Choice3')
)
```

So, the generated field in a model serializer is a `serializers.ChoiceField` with choices provided at the previously declared model level.

When it comes to validation user input from the client, DRF fails to validate float values correctly. For example, when I send:

```
{
    "myField": 1
}
```

it throws `"\"1\" is not a valid choice."`. So when I come with debugger to the line

`return self.choice_strings_to_values[six.text_type(data)]` from previously shown `to_internal()` of `ChoiceField`, I see that it literally tries to find `'1'` in choices list. When I update my choices with:

```
MY_FLOAT_CHOICES = Choices(
    (1, 'choice1', 'Choice1'),
    (1.5, 'default_value', 'Choice2'),
    (2, 'choice3', 'Choice3')
)
```

it doesn't fail, but then I have the same problem with sending `1.0` instead from `1` and it goes round and round. Should I raise an issue on the DRF repository, or there is some better option?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to convert the int key to float so it will be able to find it in the choices tuple.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    if data == '' and self.allow_blank:
        return ''

    try:
        key = six.text_type(float(data))
        return self.choice_strings_to_values[key]
    except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
        self.fail('invalid_choice', input=data)
```

Comment: This is the Rest Framework code, I cannot change that and don't want to make my own ChoiceField to override this method. Then I would have to implement more complicated logic because of different types of choices (checking types of model field etc...it just seems too complicated).